# how to countdown after mouse click is released

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a countdown when I stop clicking mouse.

this code makes a count down just when I click mouse:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
                tim -= Time.deltaTime;

                if (tim < 0)
                {
                    tim = 0;
                }

                int t = Mathf.FloorToInt(tim);
                timer.text = "timer" + t.ToString();

            }
```

I want to make a countdown when I stop clicking mouse. and then need to stop when I click it. and then start the countdown when I do not click a mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset `tim` to a constant value on mouse down

`int const COUNTDOWN_MAX = 3;`

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //reset countdown when click
        tim = COUNTDOWN_MAX;
    }
    else
    {
        //start countdown when not click
        tim -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (tim < 0)
        {
            tim = 0;
        }
    }
    //show timer
    int t = Mathf.FloorToInt(tim);
    timer.text = "timer" + t.ToString();
}
```

Comment: thank you!it works very well ...just changed tim = ? (not zero)